# which xml parser is better for parsing Mondrian Schema

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd, schema, mondrian

Currently our Mondrian Schema values held within  *.xml file. We need to extend some information from this schema and held them in a java Object.

What is the best/simplest library to use in order to read in values from this file?

Comment: What's wrong with the standard Java XML libraries?

Comment: Mondrian schema doesn't have any DTD or XSD itself ... and by standard java XML libraries you mean JAXB?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options. Mondrian uses Apache VFS to fetch the schemas, so you can implement your own file handle (something like myhandler://mondrian_schemas/my_schema.xml).

If you're managing your Mondrian instance through the MondrianServer API, you can pass your own implementations of a couple needed SPIs and get very deep control on which definition file is used and what the URLs to these files return. A basic example is [shown here](http://devdonkey.blogspot.ca/2012/09/programmatic-roles-in-mondrian.html), in the first part.

Comment: Thanks @Luc it's so helping ... i was looking for how Mondrian parse his schema? but i didn't find the answer ... so now i'm using XPath, do you think it is good for parsing Mondrian Schema ?